# How to get desired JSON output given a Pymongo cursor with Marshmallow Schema

Tags: python, pymongo, marshmallow

I am having a problem with my Marshmallow output, whereby the JSON result is:

```
[
   [
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "x":"2018-04-03 23:28:31.539895",
               "y":15.937
            }
         ],
         "sensor":"/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000077aae57/w1_slave"
      },
   ],
   {

   }
]
```

But I want it to look like:

```
[
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "x":"2018-04-03 23:37:40.612334",
            "y":16.187
         }
      ],
      "sensor":"/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000077aae57/w1_slave"
   }
]
```

I have a `get_line` function which returns a Pymongo cursor:

```
>>> get_line()
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x109162208>
```

I then define my marshmallow schemas:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class PointSchema(Schema):
    x = fields.String()
    y = fields.String()

class LineSchema(Schema):
    sensor = fields.String()
    data = fields.List(fields.Nested(PointSchema))
```

I use the following code within my flask endpoint to return the data to the client:

```
result = get_line()
output = []
for line in result:
    output.append({'sensor':line['name'], 'data': get_line(line['name'])})

return jsonify(LineSchema(many=True).dump(output))
```

I have also tried replacing `LineSchema` with:

```
class LineSchema(Schema):
    sensor = fields.String()
    data = fields.Nested(PointSchema, many=True)
```

which results in the exact same JSON output.  How should I be processing this to achieve the desired JSON?  I'm ripping my hair out with this, but want to avoid changing the client's code to accommodate.

Comment: What is `get_line` doing? Or at the very lest what does result look like when you are running this so I have some test data.

Comment: @nerdlyist Thanks for your're comment, however I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured this out...

The correct marshmallow schema to use was:

```
class LineSchema(Schema):
     sensor = fields.String()
     data = fields.Nested(PointSchema, many=True)
```

However, the reason for the strange JSON result in the form `[ [], {} ]` was that `LineSchema(many=True).dump(output)` returns a MarshalObject in the form:

```
MarshalResult(data=[{'data': [{'y': 15.937, 'x': '2018-04-03 23:28:31.539895'}], 'sensor': '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000077aae57/w1_slave'}], errors={})
```

So the correct syntax for the return was:

```
return jsonify(LineSchema(many=True).dump(output).data)
```

Comment: [This github post](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/10#issuecomment-31308326) actually suggests passing the instance and not the class into Nested, so it becomes `Nested (PointSchema(), many = true)`. Although I didn't find a significant performance increase in my code.